# Refreshing page with background video

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, html5-video, video-player

On my site, on background plays video. How i can make resuming video on the same point, when i am going to another page? Pages refreshing with ajax.
I tried to solve it by little script on the main page:

```
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
vid.addEventListener("canplay", function(e) {
  var currTime = this.currentTime;
  this.play();
 }, false
);
</script>
```

Another script, on the other html page, where i want to continue my video:

```
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.addEventListener("canplay", function(e) {
    this.currentTime = currTime;
    this.play();
 }, false
 );
</script>
```

I am getting next error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: currTime is not defined
at HTMLVideoElement.<anonymous>
```

Am i right with this solution? Will it work If i could fix this error? If answer: yes, how i can globalize this "currTime"?
Thank you.

Updated:
HTML code for video:

`<video loop muted autoplay poster="../static/images/wallpaper.png" class="fullscreen-bg__video" id="video">
    <source src="../static/videos/wallpaper.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="../static/videos/wallpaper.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>`

```
.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

on the page, where i am getting paused video the same code but with another id.

Comment: You may want to continuously read the current timestamp on the video and save that to localStorage. Then, when the page reloads, inspect that timestamp from localStorage and load the video to that time.

Comment: @daddygames yes, it sounds, like exactly what i need. how i can do this? by creating js file and reading timestamp and writing it in those file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
vid.addEventListener("canplay", function(e) {

localStorage.setItem("videoTime", this.currentTime);
  this.play();
 }, false
);
</script>
```

NOTE: `localStorage.setItem("videoTime", this.currentTime)` is only done **ONCE**. You could set the time with `setInterval()` every second to a new value.

```
setInterval(() => {localStorage.setItem("videoTime", this.currentTime);},1000);
```

After reload get item with:

```
        <script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        vid.addEventListener("canplay", function(e) {
        if(localStorage.getItem("videoTime") !== null) {
           this.currentTime = localStorage.getItem("videoTime");
        }

        this.play();
     }, false
     );
    </script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Tested it on my machine. Works with any .html file. Just paste this as script:

```
<script>
        window.onload = () => {
            var vid = document.getElementById("video");
            if(localStorage.getItem("videoTime") !== null && localStorage.getItem("videoTime") !== undefined) {
                vid.currentTime = localStorage.getItem("videoTime");   }
```

setInterval(() => {localStorage.setItem("videoTime", vid.currentTime);},1000);            }

```
        </script>
```

1. execute the script after window has loaded.
2. get vid as HTMLElement
3. check if localStorage entry with the key `vidTime` exists.
4. if yes, set vid time with `vid.currentTime = localStorage.getItem("videoTime");`
5. update every second new videoTime: `setInterval(() => {localStorage.setItem("videoTime", vid.currentTime);},1000);`

Comment: works great, but after refreshing video is paused, i tried `this.playing();` but it is still paused.

Comment: `$('myVideo').trigger('play');` does not help

Comment: `$('myVideo').get(0).play();` does not help too

Comment: `if(this.pause()){
      this.play();
   }` have not help

Comment: @AlexanderVasilchuk could you send your HTML code too please?

Comment: @AlexanderVasilchuk added an Update.